# Prometheus Node Exporter - Metrics for Interface Speed

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Prometheus Node Exporter - Metrics for Interface Speed.

node_network_speed_bytes is giving 125000000 bytes for ethernet interface. However, the actual speed of the interface on the server is 1000Mb/s.

I need to calculate bandwidth utilization. I am using below query but data is not matching.

irate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{}[1h]) / node_network_speed_bytes{}

Comment: According to metric help: `# HELP node_network_speed_bytes speed_bytes value of /sys/class/net/<iface>.`. I'd recommend to investigate meaning of this parameter.